# Wordpress - Custom Image Architecture, how?

Tags: wordpress, image, architecture

I got posts on my blog, with media images.
These have

```
<img clas="..." src="...." ..........etc......... sizes="....">
```

So my question is how can I change how WP is building my images on my website.
For example, I want it to be like just like this :

```
<img src="....." class="fine">
```

Just this. How to can I achieve that? Where can I change this?
Please help :).

Comment: You definitely need to reword your question. I doubt any user will be able to understand what you are asking. Did you mean to post some links or photos? Because the question seems to end at random places like after "Those got" and "I wanted it to be like just".

Comment: When sending images via admin panel, media, you upload images. Then I create new post, add img from media. And it submits to posts. And after submiting post on website it looks like .... oh god. where is my code, eh, didnt see. How to edit this question eh

Comment: I did some changes.